# How to pass formula field value in Crystal Report to my Form in C#?

Tags: c#

I need to pass formula field Value  in Crystal Report  to  my Form  in  C#. How can i do it ?

My Code is:

```
ReportDocument RD = new ReportDocument();
txtNumber.Text=RD.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["Formula Field Name"].Text;
```

Note: Data type Formula Field is Numeric

This code Get formula field text in Crystal Report to my form in C#.

But, i need formula field value  in Crystal Report to my form in C#?

Thank's in advance

Comment: is this field calculated from report iself?

Comment: yes, formula field is Calculated in Crystal Report.

Comment: just i need to pass formula field value from crystal report to my form in C#. For Example: i want formula field value shown in textbox or label in my form in C#.

Comment: see my answer buddy. As it's a calculated field, you **can't**. Explanation is in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm posting this answer as nobody has answered a single solution yet. Would ask the community to correct me if I'm wrong, else edit and add more to this for future references.*

The code below should fetch the *value* from the report field

```
FormulaFieldDefinition value = Report1.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["formulaName"];
```

*But* the above mentioned code **will not work** if the *Formula Field Name* is a **calculated field. Calculated fields** have **no** values until and unless **Crystal Report engine has done its rendering**.

> So what you can do best is to fetch the data you require from the **source binding** of the report itself.